# sql insert query producing extra records

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a blog.The admin uses a form to upload a new story into the database .The following code inserts the new story into the database:

```
 $insert_story="INSERT INTO story(title,date,author,intro,body,category) VALUES('$title','$date','$author','$intro','$body','$category')";

    $run_query=mysqli_query($conn,$insert_story);
```

The above statement should insert one record in the database,but the problem is that three more empty records appear :

[image]

What could be the problem here?

Comment: You may have a trigger on the table.

Comment: is this in a loop in the code, maybe? Can you share more of your code?

Comment: I think the $run_query code might be inside a loop that loops 4times,but how come empty rows are inserted need to check that in code

Comment: Your code is calling 4 inserts with only one set of data so the other 3 sets are empty.

Comment: Can you post More Code?

Comment: Where those record already in the table before you inserted? Why don't you clear the table first just to make sure...

Comment: @TheImpaler, looking at the `story_id`, you could be on to something.

Comment: Here is the entie php code<?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit_story'])){
            
            $date=$_POST['date'];
            $author=$_POST['author'];
            $category=$_POST['category'];
            $title=$_POST['title'];
            $intro=$_POST['intro'];
            $body=$_POST['body'];
            
            
        }
        
        $insert_story="INSERT INTO story(title,date,author,intro,body,category) VALUES('$title','$date','$author','$intro','$body','$category')";
        
        $run_query=mysqli_query($conn,$insert_story);
       
        ?>

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!